# how to fix 'Access violation reading location' in this code

Tags: c++, destructor

run this code i got some error like this

' Exception thrown at 0x778D7FCB (ntdll.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000014.'

This error occurs in this line

```
~UnivStudnet() {
delete[]major; // error
    }
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Person {
private:
    char * name;
public:
    Person(const char * myname) {
        name = new char[strlen(myname) + 1];
        strcpy_s(name, strlen(name), myname);
    }
    ~Person() {
        delete[]name;
    }

    void WhatYourName() const {
        cout << "My name is " << name << endl;
    }
};

class UnivStudnet : public Person {
private:
    char * major;
public:
    UnivStudnet(const char * myname, const char * const mymajor) :Person(myname) {
        major = new char[strlen(mymajor) + 1];
        strcpy_s(major, strlen(major), mymajor);
    }
    ~UnivStudnet() {
        delete[]major;
    }

    void WhoAreYou() const {
        WhatYourName();
        cout << "My major is " << major << endl;
    }
};

int main(void) {

    UnivStudnet st1("kim", "Mathenatics");
    st1.WhoAreYou();
    UnivStudnet st2("hong", "Physiscs");
    st2.WhoAreYou();
    return 0;
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: @hsalimi even there is better to do in general here that has no importance because no delete from a base class pointer

Comment: Implement copy/move constructor/assignment as well, otherwise you will delete the raw pointer twice if you do copy operations.

Comment: Are you sure the code you give us produce the invalid access ? Why do you not use std::string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strcpy_s usage is suspect.

```
    major = new char[strlen(mymajor) + 1];
    strcpy_s(major, strlen(major), mymajor);
```

The second parameter to `strcpy_s` is the allocated size of the buffer specified by the first parameter.  (And I just now realized - based on another answer that `strlen(major)` is undefined before you copy to it!

You are allocating the buffer to be large enough to hold the string, but the subsequent call to strcpy_s is indicating that `major` isn't big enough to hold the entire string including the null char.

Better:

```
    size_t len = strlen(mymajor) + 1;
    major = new char[len];
    strcpy_s(major, len, mymajor);
```

Repeat the above pattern for the base class `name` parameter as well.

Answer (score 4):

There are bugs on the two `strcpy_s` lines.

```
strcpy_s(name, strlen(name), myname);
```

should be

```
strcpy_s(name, strlen(myname)+1, myname);
```

and likewise

```
strcpy_s(major, strlen(major), mymajor);
```

should be

```
strcpy_s(major, strlen(mymajor)+1, mymajor);
```

Calling `strlen` on the newly-allocated char arrays `name` and `major` which have indeterminate values, causes undefined behavior which is the cause of your crash.

Comment: I think the OP went by the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s?view=vs-2017) which states that the second parameter is the size of the destination string.

Comment: Which here is `strlen(myname) + 1` since it's newed that size on the line just above.  `strlen(name)` does not give the allocated length of `name`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just wanted to point why the OP might have made this error (apart from not adding 1). Upvoted the answer by the way. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could go more C++-way:

You need to declare:

```
virtual ~Person()
```

destructor in base class and then:

```
class UnivStudnet : public Person {
private:
    std::string major;
public:
    UnivStudnet(const char * myname, const char * const mymajor) :Person(myname), major(mymajor) {
    }
    virtual ~UnivStudnet() {
    }
...
```

This way you will achieve what you need and do not think about memory allocation/deallocation. Remember to `#include <string>` header.

Same way do it in `Person` class.